# SqlKata - Join on string value and with ISNULL condition

Tags: c#, .net, sqlkata

I would like to join on static string value in SqlKata BUT not able to figure out how to do that.

**this is how my query needs to be**

```
LEFT JOIN [tblUserGroupMembers] AS [TUGM] ON ([TUGM].[UserGroupID] = [TUG].[UserGroupId] AND [TUGM].[UserType] = 'Primary')
LEFT JOIN [tblUsers] AS [TU] ON [TU].[UserId] = ISNULL([TIA].[UserId],[TUGM].[UserId])
```

> as you can see, i would like to join `TUGM.UserType` = **Primary**  and in another join 
>   `[TU].[UserId] = ISNULL([TIA].[UserId],[TUGM].[UserId])`

SqlKata Query:

```
var dbQuery = db.Query("tblInvoices AS TI")
            .Join("tblInvoiceActions AS TIA", "TIA.InvoiceID", "TI.InvoiceID")
            .Join("APM_MASTER__INVOICE AS AMI", "AMI.InvoiceID", "TI.InvoiceID")
            .LeftJoin("tblUserGroups AS TUG", "TUG.UserGroupId", "TI.UserGroupId")
            .LeftJoin("tblUserGroupMembers AS TUGM",
                j => j.On("TUGM.UserGroupID", "TUG.UserGroupId")
                .On("TUGM.UserType","['Primary']"))
           .LeftJoin("tblUsers AS TU", "TU.UserId", "[ISNULL(TIA.UserId,TUGM.UserId)]")
           .LeftJoin("tblConnections AS TC", "TC.ConnectionID", "TI.ConnectionID");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Join` methods have an overload that accepts a lambda in the 2nd parameter to provide the full flexibility.
Using it with `WhereRaw` to write a raw expression, off course you should be aware of SQL injection here.

So you can use it here:

```
db.Query("tblInvoices as TI").LeftJoin(
   "tblUsers as TU", 
   j => j.WhereRaw("TU.UserId = ISNULL(...)")
)
```

Comment: perfect..let me try this out and see what happens.